# Trusting the results of a binary vector comparison

Tags: bootstrap, binary-data

I have two pretty long binary vectors ($\sim 3$ mi positions), and I found the distance between then using Jaccard's Index $J=\frac{a}{a + b + c}$. After getting the result, I asked myself how much can I trust this value.

I thought about two alternatives, and would like to hear your advice to be sure that they are appropriate.

1. Randomize both vectors multiple times and check with z-score or
   t-test, where my original result is falling within this random
   distribution.
2. Resample with replacement (Bootstrap) the vectors and verify if my
   original result is always within the 95% Confidence Interval.

The issue with the first alternative is that even after 10.000 randomizations, many times the original result is very far from the distribution mean (z-score $= \sim 20$).

===========================================

Here are more details about the problem at hand.

The binary vectors are indicators of change in my samples - one indicates a change, zero otherwise. One vector represents one characteristic, and the other vector another characteristic. They are in principle varying independently and subject to distinct external influence.

However, my objective is to find out if these two characteristics are in fact changing together - i.e., when the characteristic represented by one vector changes, the other characteristic changes as well. And importantly, how often could this "*vector similarity*" occur by chance.

For instance, please consider:

Vector A - `0001111`

Vector B - `0001011`

and

Vector C - `01010`

Vector D - `10100`

In this case, vectors A and B seem to be pretty related, but vectors C and D not so much.

Now I'm trying to figure out rigorous ways to assess how this vector similarity could arrive by chance.

Comment: What are `a`,`b`,`c` in `J`? How are you randomizing in #1? How are you resampling in #2? Is the randomization/resampling destroying the interesting structure of the data or preserving it?

Comment: Answers to questions like this require information about possible sources of variation in the data.  If there are no sources of variation, then $J$ is what it is and is as trustworthy as mathematics and computers can make it.  If there are strong positive serial correlations in the vectors, which are viewed as realizations of stochastic processes, then the true value that $J$ is apparently trying to estimate may be completely uncertain. The reality probably lies somewhere between these two extremes, but *you need to supply enough information to help us determine where.*

Comment: @Memming - To randomize the vector in #1 I used R function *sample*, without replacement in each vector separately. In #2, I used again *sample* in both vectors at the same time - keeping the "match" between the vectors in place - and this time, with replacement.